# Changing font styles of submit button

Tags: css

I want to change just the font-size and font-weight of a submit and keep all the other default browser styles.

In my version of Chrome at least, it seems styles are ignored unless you change the background colour. Is there a way to keep the browser defaults but just increase the size and weight?

```
<input type="submit" style="font-size: 55px;" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkC52/

I believe this is a Chrome issue with my install.

Comment: The jsFiddle you provided seems to be working. It has submit button with large font without setting background color.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in Chrome...

Comment: your might have some problem here but in fact your question does not make much sense, try rephrasing it as soon as possible before the number of closing votes reaching 5.

Comment: Okay, I think something is up with my Chrome then. That explains why I couldn't find any help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Form controls are system elements. You need to reset system button style by using css `appereance` properties:

```
input {
    -webkit-appereance: none;
    -moz-appereance: none;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fkC52/3/

This is what I did, just added `font-weight` and `font-size` to the CSS.
I tried the jsfiddle in Chrome and it works, so I don't see the problem.

I suggest to use a `class` or an `id` to change just one submit.